# Run Lambda When Multiple Dependent Files Are in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I have 4 Lambda functions scheduled at differing regular intervals to download xml files from an external service, transform them to json and place them in an S3 bucket.

- File A is updated every 28 days
- File B is updated every 5 minutes
- File C is updated every 60 seconds
- File D is updated every 60 seconds

I need to run another Lambda after when one or more of the files is uploaded to create another file. If A, B, C & D are updated on the same cycle I only want the lambda to run once.

What would be the best way to go about doing this accounting for potential error situations, e.g. one file could not be downloaded (I'd probably like to use the last good version of file).

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is just put all that in one Lambda function. Is file A that large that you can't update it every 60 seconds? Maybe other things are restricting that, but to me it seems like it wouldn't cost a dime to just update every file every minute. Without versioning the objects would just be overwritten. You could even write your Lambda function to create a backup of the previous file so you can always use that one if an error occured.

At the end of that one Lambda function you create the new file, and voila.

Comment: I had a think about it and I definitely complicated the process too much. 

As I'm using dynamodb as a temporal store I set the lambdas on scheduler and inserted the records in their own table with the ValidFrom date being when the Lambda was being called and the ValidTo being the next tick. I realised all the files actually really rely on each other being up to date so if one is missing then I can't build a new state from them in a lambda api call its then classed as a missed download so I use the last full state generated.